# Magento: How to remove extra white background from uploaded image from admin

Tags: image, magento, background, trim

i am working in Magento and here is what i am trying to achieve

i) When a user upload any product image from admin, i want to remove extra white background around the image and then save it.

Can any one tell me from where to start this.

Thanks

Comment: That would also be helpful to me...if someone can tell me which class is used to upload product image from admin. So that i can extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be `Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader`.
Or you can hook to event `catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after`  .

Basically the work starts at `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_GalleryController`  so you can go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Extra white background appears when the image uploaded is not the same dimension where it is requested.

For example, the image uploaded is 200x200 and it is called some where at a proportion of 300x200. So the image will resize to fit for the position without being stretched out rather resizeing it to the proportion with extra white space. you can use the following code to change the background color

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->backgroundColor(array(0,0,0))->resize(310); ?>
```

Cheers!

Amjath

Comment: Amjath is correct here, if you are uploading an image not the same dimensions as you're showing on frontend. If you want to cut out the white background completely from the picture (to get a transparent shoe image in example), as I understood you were trying to do, you need to do customization